# Listing & Entering exam scores using jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatables, viewmodel

I use jQuery DataTable in order to list the exam scores of students belonging to a group. However, I have no idea as I have not found a suitable approach on the web. Here is my entity relationships on the image below. I can use DataTable, but I am confised how to group these entities **so that all of the students having a LabGroup  will be listed even if they have no grade**. So, which approach should I follow? Should I make the Experiment or LabGroup as the origin of ViewModel?

[image]

On the other hand, the table should be seen as showb below:

[image]

Comment: What is the information you want displayed in the table?

Comment: read about outer joins

Comment: @madalinivascu I know it, but I am not sure if it is the best method for my situation. On the other hand, I have not found about how to use a custom sql query in lambda expression and fill the ViewModel via it. Any idea?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the table view. On the other hand, I hope there is no problem regarding to entity relations?

Comment: @madalinivascu Any idea about that?